# Зависимость ссылок

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, css

**http://demo13.ocjoy.com/
На этом сайте решена эта проблема, но не могу понять все равно как!**

Есть две ссылки

а1 и а2

Как сделать так чтобы если

- при а2 просто у а1 был 1 бекгроунд,
- при а2.active у а1 был совсем другой бекгроунд

Есть меню категорий в интернет Магазине

[image: img]

**Скрипт отвечающий за развертывание подкатегорий при нажатии**

```
$(document).ready(function(){$('.sliEsq').click(function(){$(this).parent().children('.sliesQ').toggle('fast');return false;});});
```

Скрипт отвечающий за смену картинки (+) на картинку (-) при нажатии, картинка присваивается через background в CSS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.sliEsq').on('click', function(){$( this ).toggleClass( "open" );});});
```

**Собственно код ссылок а1 и а2 соответственно**

```
<a title="Развернуть" style=" margin-top:0px; margin-left:-14px; width:11px;  height:11px; float:left;" href="javascript://" class="sliEsq"></a>  <a  style="margin-bottom: 10px;" href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>">  <?php echo $child['name']; ?></a>
```

Теперь суть проблемы, при переходе в категорию , автоматически разворачиваются подкатегории, те как бы становятся открытыми. но картинка остается (+), соответсвенно есди нажимаешь свернуть, токартинка становится (-).\
Те у активной категории с развернутыми подкатегориями должана быть картинка (-), но нет.

**CMS OPENCART**

**При переходе в категорию за автоматическое раскрытие подкатегорий отвечает**

```
.box-category > ul > li a.active + ul 
{display: block}
```

Comment: Класс "active" появляется у второй ссылки динамически или, к примеру, при загрузке страницы с определенным параметром? Если первое, то по какому событию добавляется/убирается класс? Если ближе ко второму, то зачем тут JS? Кроме того, хорошо бы показать, что вы уже сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Класс актив появляется при загрузке страницы по этой ссылке. Никаких наметок нет, потому что не знаю  с чего начать.

Comment: @Паша Сокольчик, вы же как-то и на что-то ориентируетесь при добавлении класса "active" к ссылке №2? Так почему же нельзя на это же ориентироваться для ссылки №1? **if ... else ...** или тернарный оператор - разве не могут быть использованы тут?

Comment: Я просто в этих делх не особо разбираюсь. Это через CSS решается или через ЯВУ, желательно с примером, за ранее благодарен.

Comment: @Паша Сокольчик

ЯВУ  - язык высокого уровня

Ява  - язык программирования Java

Яваскрипт - язык программирования Javascript

java != javascript

Comment: @Паша Сокольчик, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось. (не разбираетесь идите учите, либо нанимайте, здесь вам не форум бесплатных программистов)

Comment: @Паша Сокольчик, как я могу вам что-то советовать, если не знаю что и к чему там у вас? Хуже всего, что по ходу пьесы, вы сами скорее всего не в курсе. )) Хоть намек дайте, что ли... Вы какую-то CMS используете, сами пишите, какой серверный язык и т.д. Что это за ссылки? Какую роль они выполняют? От чего зависит активное состояние каждой из них?

Comment: Подправил вопрос

Comment: И все затихли=)